# Office 365 Data Retention?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, data-recovery

Hoping someone could help clear this up -- basically we are looking to configure data retention policies in Office 365.  Reading through some of the articles on how data retention policies work with regard to emails + recoverable items, I'm just a bit unclear on the below.

Say for example I create a retention policy to retain emails for 7 years (based on original creation date of the email) and choose the option to not delete after 7 years.  If a user deletes a bunch of emails either through clearing deleted items or shift + delete, and we find out 3-4 months later, would we be able to recover those emails (provided they are not older than 7 years) and if so, how?  Or would the emails not be recoverable since it would be past 30 days of them being cleared out of the Recoverable Items/Purges folder of the mailbox?

Appreciate any help in advance on clearing this up!